# Con arrays bidimensional en c#

Tags: c#, array, matriz, array-bidimensional

Tengo que hacer un trabajo para la facultad en donde consiste en el juego "tirar dados". La consigna dice:tirar 5 dados, seis veces. (array bidimensional 5 columnas y de 6 filas,por cada tiro almacenar el valor de cada dado en un array.
Luego de todo ese proceso el programa deberá mostrar los resultados indicando la cantidad de veces que salio cada valor.
Llegue hasta almacenar cada tiro en un array.Se que debo usar un for para recorrerlo pero si alguien es tan amable de decirme o orientarme de como hacer para que me muestre la cantidad de veces que salio cada valor, porque estuve pensandolo por un buen tiempo y no se como hacerlo.
Aqui les dejo el codigo que llegue hacer:

```
           int jugada = 1;
        
           while(jugada<=6)
           {
            Console.Write("Presione una tecla para comenzar la jugada ");
            Console.WriteLine("\nJugando...Tiro:"+jugada++);
            Console.ReadLine();
           }
          
           int[,] dados = new int[5,6]; //int como variable de tipo entero. El new es para reservar espacio en memoria
           Random al = new Random();
           for ( int f = 0; f < 6 ; f++)// este for recorre la
           {
            Console.Write("\nTiro :");
            
            for (int c = 0; c < 5; c++)
            {
                dados[c, f]= al.Next(1,7);
                Console.Write(dados[c, f]+" ");
                
            }
            Console.WriteLine(" ");
           }
         Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te faltaria hacer un array para cargar la respuesta y luego recorrer el array para mostrar los resultados.

```
       int jugada = 1;
       int[] resultado = new int[6];
    
       while(jugada<=6)
       {
        Console.Write("Presione una tecla para comenzar la jugada ");
        Console.WriteLine("\nJugando...Tiro:"+jugada++);
        Console.ReadLine();
       }
      
       int[,] dados = new int[5,6]; //int como variable de tipo entero. El new es para reservar espacio en memoria
       Random al = new Random();
       for ( int f = 0; f < 6 ; f++)// este for recorre la
       {
        Console.Write("\nTiro :");
        
        for (int c = 0; c < 5; c++)
        {
            dados[c, f]= al.Next(1,7);
            Console.Write(dados[c, f]+" ");
            GuardarResultado(dados[c,f]);
            
        }
        Console.WriteLine(" ");
       }

     MostrarResultado();
     Console.ReadKey(true);
}
private void GuardarResultado(int numero)
{
   switch(numero)
   {
      case 1: resultado[0] += resultado[0]+1;
              break;
      case 2: resultado[1] += resultado[1]+1;
              break;
      //haces lo mismo con el resto de los numeros hasta completar el 6
   }
}
private void MostrarResultados()
{
  for(int i=0; i <6; i++)
  {
    Console.WriteLine($"Cantidad de repeticiones del numero {i} fueron: {resultado[i].Count()}";
  }
}
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!

Comment: @DarkBlue si te sirvio y fue la correcta, marcala como tal.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando se tira un dado, el valor aleatorio obtenido se usa como índice para incrementar la matriz en esa posición:

```
for (int c = 0; c < 5; c++) {
           dados[c, al.Next(1, 6)]++;
    }
```

Luego al imprimir el primer índice de la matriz es el número del dado y el segundo índice es la cantidad de veces que cayó ese lado:

```
// imprimir resultados
for (int c = 0; c < 5; c++) {
  Console.WriteLine($ "Dado {c + 1}");

  for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    Console.WriteLine($ "Cara {i + 1} : {dados[c, i]}");
  }

}
```

El código completo:

```
public static void Main(string[] args) {

  int jugada = 1;

  while (jugada <= 6) {

    Console.Write("Presione una tecla para comenzar la jugada ");
    Console.WriteLine("\nJugando...Tiro:" + jugada++);
    Console.ReadLine();
  }

  int[, ] dados = new int[5, 6]; //int como variable de tipo entero. El new es para reservar espacio en memoria
  Random al = new Random();
  for (int f = 0; f < 6; f++) // hacer 6 tiros
  {

    // incrementar en uno el valor obtenido en el tiro
    // para el dado c
    for (int c = 0; c < 5; c++) {
      dados[c, al.Next(1, 6)]++;

    }

  }

  // imprimir resultados
  for (int c = 0; c < 5; c++) {
    Console.WriteLine($ "Dado {c + 1}");

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
      Console.WriteLine($ "Cara {i + 1} : {dados[c, i]}");
    }

  }

  Console.ReadKey(true);
}
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!!!